# ant target doesn't exist but gets executed

Tags: ant

i have never seen this strange -

i am into maintenance project where i got a build.xml and i never installed ant. ant is bundled into the project and so i use -

ant deploy_project.

but when i look at build.xml i cannot find any target named "deploy_project".

can anyone help me how the "deploy_project" target gets executed without this target being present in build.xml?

I suspect that since i didn't install ant by myself and is bundled with the project, any configuration of ant may have been overridden...but how to find  it is where i am stuck, can any one pls help me?

(I am sure the target isn't present in build.xml).

thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command:

```
$ ant -p
```

This will usually print out all the targets in your `build.xml`. Or at least the ones with descriptions.

Also look for `<import file="...">` statements in your `build.xml`. These allow you to import other Ant build files which can contain targets that aren't in your build.xml. I suspect, if you do a search for the string `deploy_project` in your `build.xml`, and you can't find a target by that name, you have an import statement somewhere in your `build.xml`, so search for `<import`.

Comment: thank you ! i have been able to find this in one of the build.xml files which was imported. thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are SURE that the target is not present, and you are not specifying the build file with -f option, then only 1 explanation I can think of -

your ANT_HOME is somewhere else and there will be another build.xml there.

(Quickest way to check is find it - `SET for Windows` `echo $PATH for Unix`), find the value for ANT_HOME and  in the same directory, a build.xml will be present with your ****INVISIBLE**** target

---

If you have searched the C: drive and still cannot find any build.xml, then the bundled ANT you have might be a customized one or an ANT wrapper. Meaning have a .bat file called ant.bat which accepts `deploy_project` as an argument and then maps it to another task using variable substitution. So look for a batch file `ant.bat` or anything titled ant.

Comment: i checked ant_home using set command on CMD, but it doesn't list Ant_Home variable. Also I did a "search for file named build.xml" on my C: drive to see if any build.xml has this target, but couldn't find anything..!!

Comment: check the variable PATH.. it might contain something like Path = "C:\..\..\..ant1.x.y\

Comment: if you have searched the C: drive and still cannot find any build.xml, see the updated answer

Comment: `If you are SURE that the target is not present, and you are not specifying the build file with -f option, then only 1 explanation I can think of - `.. nope~ We need to make sure that there isn't any `<import>` in his build.xml.